# How do you add image files from a folder with Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, file, awt

Closest thing I found was: [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file/326440#326440)
I've used this, looking for line breaks and using a while hasNext() loop, but I was wondering if there is an equivalent for image files? I would want to add images from a folder up to a point or until all images are added

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please ask a better question...

Comment: What do you mean *"add images from a file"*?  Do you have a list of images inside a file which relate to images on a disk, or do you mean you want to list a directory of images??

Comment: The latter is correct Mad. I meant from a folder, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list the contents of a directory, you could start with...

```
File[] contents = new File("/path/to/images").listFiles();
```

You would now simply need to iterate over the list to determine how to handle each `File` individually...

Now, you can save yourself some time and supply a `FileFilter` which will allow you to pre-emptively discard files which you may not be interested in...

```
File[] contents = new File("path").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        String name = pathname.getName().toLowerCase();
        return name.endsWith(".png")
                || name.endsWith(".jpg")
                || name.endsWith(".jpeg")
                || name.endsWith(".gif")
                || name.endsWith(".bmp");
    }
});
```

Once you have the list of image files, you need to iterate the list

```
for (File imageFile : contents) {
    // Deal with the file...
}
```

Have a look at [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more details

Equally, you could use the new `Files` API...

```
try {
    final Path master = new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\MegaTokyo").toPath();
    Files.walkFileTree(master, new FileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            return dir.equals(master) ? FileVisitResult.CONTINUE : FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println(file);
            // Process the file result here
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```